# Active or passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

Guests are unwelcome. Is it passive or active? The verb here is tranisitive and the guests aren't the one that unwelcomes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This is allowed", is this passive voice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170620/this-is-allowed-is-this-passive-voice)

Comment: The verb is neither transitive nor intransitive: it is a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics))

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, *unwelcome* is definitely an adjective (there is no such verb as *unwelcome*), functioning as the subject complement.

A sentence with a passive voice would be

> The guests are *welcomed* by ...

as both past and past participle of *welcome* is (or *are*!) *welcomed*.

Answer (score 0):

“Are’ is the verb used in this sentence.Hence this sentence belongs to Present Tense.

It is not in:

1. Continuous tense, prefect tense or perfect continuous tense.Hence it is in Simple Present Tense and in affirmative form.
2. Formula for this sentence in Passive voice is as follow:

Subject+ helping verb + Past participle.+................

Note: This is no past participle form of the verb ‘unwelcome’.

Hence it is not in passive voice.